# call swift class (derived from NSObject class) init from objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have a Swift class that inherits from a NSObject-derived class written in Objective-C.

```
@objc class DisplayMessage : JSQMessage, BaseModel
{
 init(var userId:String, var userName:String, var message:String, var group:Group)
    {
//...
     }
}
```

How can i call this init from Objective-C?

I only see the JSQMessage (the NSObject-derived class written in obj-c) inits.. + a default init method with no parameters

**UPDATE**

i inserted an @objc in front of the init in swift and i get the error

> Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter 1,2,3,4 cannot be represented in objective-c

After i saw this, i changed the String type to NSString and the Group class is already @objc; I still receive the same error

**UPDATE 2**

i've tried the same thing with Int initializer and i get the same error

```
  @objc init(var numberLol:Int)
{
    super.init(senderId: "", senderDisplayName: "", date:nil,  text: nil)
}
```

Comment: have you tried replacing `String` by `NSString`?

Comment: yes, i've mentioned this in UPDATE 1

Comment: oops!, sorry, I miss that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so the answer was that i have to remove the "var" from each parameter in the init. Why? idk

Comment: Why were you using `var` in the first place?